# Is it bad design to manually add/remove rows from a QAbstractItemModel?

Tags: c++, qt, qabstractitemmodel

I have a class that inherits from `QAbstractItemModel` that I'm using to represent a tree data structure.  As part of my design, there are instances where user interaction in one part of the tree will cause rows to be added/removed in some other, possibly distant part of the model.  I do this via direct communication between my nodes.  That is, `QABstractItemModel::insertRows()` and `removeRows()` are not invoked in this case.  This has created some challenges in getting the model view to refresh correctly and I suspect that the `QAbstractItemModel` class wasn't really designed with this type of behavior in mind.  Is this possibly a bad design?  Should I only be adding/removing nodes through `QAbstractItemModel`'s built-in member functions?

Comment: Are you manually firing all signals?  You can test this to some extent by mocking.  Have a toy view connect to **every** signal that a `QAbstractItemModel` exposes, and log what happens.  Using a toy `QAbstractItemModel`, remove some rows, logging what happens.  Now hook the toy view to your real `QAbstractItemModel` and have it manipulate rows, with logging.  Are the logs similar, or different?

Comment: I don't emit any signals when I do the manual insertion/deletion; I just made my `node` class a `friend class` of my model, so I can call its protected member functions like `beginInsertRows()` etc.  What should I do with the log data I'd get from your method?  Should I manually emit the signals that aren't showing up in my custom model class?

Comment: Yes.  Or read up on model view.  Views rely on signals (or similar) to reflect changes to models.